# AJAX call to PHP method->missing arguments 2 & 3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Similar questions have been asked, but I can't find any that deal with my issue in a way that I understand, so here's my version:

I'm using JQuery's `.ajax()` in an attempt to send data to a PHP method, but I'm not passing the variables correctly, and getting this: `PHP Warning:  Missing argument 3 for ControllerModuleTesting::modifyAttemptsAllowed()`.

Sample Code:

From the PHP class

```
public function modifyAttemptsAllowed($action, $customer_id, $test_id) {
    $this->log->write($action);//Writes to the error log, returns empty array at present.
    return 2;//Arbitrary value standing in place for logic.
}
```

The HTML button (with bootstrap 3 markup) that's triggering the Javascript function:

```
<button type="button" onclick="modifyAttemptsAllowed('decrement', '2', '35')" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Decrease Attempts Allowed" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button>
```

The AJAX request:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function modifyAttemptsAllowed(action, customer_id, test_id) {
var request = $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=module/testing/modifyAttemptsAllowed&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {//I thought this was where the variables were named and passed...
        action: action,
        customer_id: customer_id,
        test_id: test_id    
        },

    success: function(json) {//
        console.log(json);
        alert(json);
    }
});
//Redundant? 
request.done(function(text) {
    console.log(text);
    alert(text);
});
}
//--></script>
```

I'm completely new to AJAX, and have gotten this far by looking at example code and reading the jQuery.ajax() documentation.  Clearly, there is still a fair bit that I don't understand.

Comment: is parameters getting added to button correctly??

Comment: Yes, question edited to clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are tying to post the value in ajax and trying t access them as parameters.
It will not work. Change the function like this.

```
public function modifyAttemptsAllowed() {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    $customer_id = $_POST['customer_id'];
    $test_id = $_POST['test_id'];
    $this->log->write($action);//Writes to the error log, returns empty array at present.
    return 2;//Arbitrary value standing in place for logic.
}
```

This should help you.

Comment: Yep.  Worked like a charm.  Modified your answer slightly to work within the system I'm using.  `$_POST['action']` -> `$this->request->post['action']`.